# Is it a must to have normals for terrain rendering when we use lighting

Tags: directx

While using lighting is it a must to have vertex with normals enabled, for example D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_NORMAL | D3DFVF_TEX1

Becaue My Project works with Normals and without Normals its just black. But my friend's work without Normals :/ Why is that ?

Comment: `D3DFVF`? Didn't this stuff go out of fashion after D3D8?

Comment: I know it's there. But it is no longer necessary, because there are other, more general, ways to specify vertex formats. It is intended for the fixed-functino pipeline, which hasn't been relevant since DX8

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have different lighting models. Partially [quoting from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174694%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The Direct3D light model generalizes light into two types: ambient light and direct light. Each has different attributes, and each interacts with the material of a surface in different ways. Ambient light is light that has been scattered so much that its direction and source are indeterminate: it maintains a low level of intensity everywhere. The indirect lighting used by photographers is a good example of ambient light. Ambient light in Direct3D, as in nature, has no real direction or source, only a color and intensity. In fact, the ambient light level is completely independent of any objects in a scene that generate light. Ambient light does not contribute to specular reflection.
>
> Direct light is the light generated by a source within a scene; it always has color and intensity, and it travels in a specified direction. Direct light interacts with the material of a surface to create specular highlights, and its direction is used as a factor in shading algorithms, including Gouraud shading. When direct light is reflected, it does not contribute to the ambient light level in a scene. The sources in a scene that generate direct light have different characteristics that affect how they illuminate a scene.

It's likely that your friend is using more ambient light, while you are using directional lighting and therefore you need to specify normals to you geometry so that the lighting model can calculate the correct colours.

Another possibility is that your friend is using a texture for the terrain and is not using lighting at all. You need to compare your code more closely to see what the difference is, and edit your post if anything is unclear.

**EDIT**
The following render states may differ between the two projects, so check all of these carefully:

- D3DRS_LIGHTING
- D3DRS_COLORVERTEX
- D3DRS_NORMALIZENORMALS

Also, check for the following calls on the D3D device:

- `SetMaterial`
- `LightEnable`
- `SetLight`

If any of these are different, can you show the two sets of code in your original question?

Comment: No We both did the same thing, I have to Custom Vertex with Normals and Without Normals and He has only one Custom Vertex that is without Normals, But mine works with normals while without normals its just blacked out. And Yeah we haven't set ambient light. We both have Direct Lights :o Any Possibility ?

Comment: @DilhanGeeth - does his custom vertex have colour defined? Also compare your render states - lighting same? Colour mode same?

Comment: Yeah everything same, I mean the Vertex Format is D3DFVF_XYZ|D3DFVF_TEX1 we haven't used color u meant DIFFUSE right ? We didnt use it

Comment: Everything is same. Code is very big that i cannot upload everything here , Light Class , Terrain Class and More inherited classes. I just want to know if direct light can be rendered on a terrain of Custom Vertex with D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_TEX1 and if so how ? Because My friend got it working.

Comment: @DilhanGeeth - if everything *is* the same then you *must* get the same result, but you don't. Therefore, something *is* different, and I'm just trying to help you find what it is by pointing out the likely places. If your code is too big to upload, then there's not much more I can suggest - sorry.